# Как сделать такой похожий слайдер?

Tags: javascript, css

[Слайдер](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/417005246752014274/feedback/?invite_code=7c3e82287b164a05b0155fc669691205&sender_id=417005384155291210)

при помощи какого инструмента можно сделать такой слайдер ?

fancybox не будет ...
slick slider тоже не оч подходит .

В интернете особо примеров таких похожих не получается у меня найти.

Помогите , пожалуйста , прям очень срочно надо, а найти похожее не получается,а идеи особо тоже нет.

Comment: почему slick не подходит? слайдер это ведь только переключение картинок, стилизуете вы самостоятельно

Comment: там еще так есть , что нажав на картинку которая например третья , то ее он должен показать как главную . Посмотрите внимательнее + там еще так , что первый слайд он сбоку и тд , а не в центре .

Comment: Вполне можно такое сделать, использовав шаблон Slider Syncing от Slick

Comment: ну это делается через API слайдера, ничего сложного там нет, должно быть что-то по типу: "sliderCenter: true" (не работал со slick), в Swiper Slider точно есть такое, абсолютно всё можно задать через стили, слайдер можно использовать любой

Comment: @vantal вы имеете ввиду что то типа этого https://codepen.io/RTW/pen/QGXoLL ?

Comment: @meine да всегда не оч шло со слайдерами , поэтому как то я с ними на долёком ВЫ скажем так

Comment: @vantal  там просто не знаю как сделать чтобы первый активный слайд увеличивался в размерах

Comment: @meine выше написал - используйте свои стили, готовое решение вы вряд ли найдете

Comment: @meine как будто никто до  меня такие слайдера не делал :(\

Comment: @XXXXXX может на просторах интернетов и есть готовое решение, но на его поиски уйдет намного больше времени, чем на написание своего решения, тем более направление, куда копать мы с вами уже определили

Comment: @vantal да я бы взял этот https://codepen.io/RTW/pen/QGXoLL просто убрал бы верхний и оставил бы нижний . Просто не понимаю как картинку сделать такую большую на активном  слайде

Comment: @XXXXXX вам нужно не большую делать при активном, а маленькую в нижнем слайдере, можно ее например обрезать, используя `overflow: hidden`

Comment: @vantal может я не правильно выразился ... вы видели в примере моего вопроса.. там первый слайд всегда огромный. Я это имею ввиду. https://prnt.sc/sk9phu

Comment: https://codepen.io/NeedHate/pen/dyYwdbG , где активный слайд со своими стилямми.